# How do I indicate there's content below the currently visible area?

Tags: navigation

The sidebar navigation on my web app has too many links and the user needs to go over to the side nav and scroll down manually to see the other links.

Example:

[image]

After settings, there are a few more links, but this is what the users see when they land on the page. How can I indicate that there are more links down the page?

Thanks

Comment: Is this a hamburger menu drawer menu on mobile, or for desktop as well?

Comment: This menu becomes a hamburger menu when it hits the tablet breakpoint, but for desktop the user will not be able to close this menu.

Answer (score 1):

### Try consolidating nav categories, or display persistent visual indicators to suggest scrolling or hidden elements using layers and shadows.

If you don't have a say over the categories for each top level navigation node (and cannot reduce the number of them), then you can use some shadow at bottom to indicate items below the viewport.

**Try making a lofi mock with shadows to cut off items, and ask users to perform a task with nodes below the viewport.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNLqnp.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>